# Boundary conditions in a four point bend test

Tags: boundary-conditions, solid-mechanics

I am looking into the four-point bend test, such as one in this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Shz2wogrqIY).

Sample screenshot from the video illustrating the problem:
[image]

I am a little confused as to how the loads are prescribed numerically as boundary conditions. My intuition tells me that the object has to have a Dirichlet BC somewhere. But it appears that the 4 supports (2 on top and 2 on bottom) exert the vertical loads, hence they should be all Neumann BCs.

Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Comment: The forces you show at the bottom of the beam are modeled as Dirichlet BCs; y-displacement equals zero at both points and x-displacement equal zero at one of the two points.

Comment: Oh hmm. Why aren't both x-displacements at the bottom zero? If only one is zero, then it seems we would lose symmetry?

Comment: The x-displacement at one point is required to restrain rigid body motion in that direction. But, it is permissible to set x-displacement equal zero at both points.

Comment: Ah I see. Would you expect the results from a simulation to differ significantly when setting both points' x-displacement to zero or just one one of them?

Answer (score 2):

You could also take advantage of the symmetry of the problem. As an added advantage you end up with a mesh with half the elements.

I would just consider half of the beam and add roller constraints on D and also on the midplane of the beam, as presented in the following schematic.

[image]

This represents a mixed boundary condition in D. Horizontally, it has prescribed zero traction, and vertically a prescribed displacement of zero..